# ffmpeg drawtext initialization error

Tags: windows, powershell, fonts, ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert an image sequence to a video file with some text overlay(eventually frame counter).

The command I am using

```sh
ffmpeg -r 24 -y -i mambo_%05d.png -i ..\3DW_Mambo.wav \
  -vf drawtext="fontfile=/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='test' " test.mp4
```

Unfortunately everytime I try running it, it can't seem to find the font.
I've seen other people succesfully use the same syntax, so not sure what I might be doing different?

I've checked that the font is named correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Carl suggests](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/ticket/2166)
double escaping

```sh
-vf drawtext="fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/arial.ttf:text='test'"
```

Comment: That worked. What an odd quirk. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! after a lot of searching, your reply help me. Here it's my complete command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i input.jpg -vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/Fonts/calibril.ttf:text='Text':fontcolor=white:fontsize=120:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" output.jpg
```