# ffmpeg drawtext fontfile error "Cannot find a valid font for family Sans"

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, fonts

I'm using ffmpeg to burn frame number into video. I suspect the error has something to do with file path.

Here's my command

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile='E\:\\ffmpegTool\\bin\\arialbd.ttf':fontsize=30: fontcolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text=%{expr\\\\\:n+1}: box=1" -y out.mp4
```

I've tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/589214/ffmpeg-drawtext-initialization-error), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103808/ffmpeg-drawtext-could-not-load-fontface-from-file) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063394/ffmpeg-giving-text-not-found-error). They didn't work

Here's the error

```
ffmpeg version N-85091-g23ae3cc Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-nvenc --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib
  libavutil      55. 57.100 / 55. 57.100
  libavcodec     57. 88.100 / 57. 88.100
  libavformat    57. 70.100 / 57. 70.100
  libavdevice    57.  5.100 / 57.  5.100
  libavfilter     6. 81.100 /  6. 81.100
  libswscale      4.  5.100 /  4.  5.100
  libswresample   2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libpostproc    54.  4.100 / 54.  4.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'E:\ffmpegTool\bin\00872.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2017-04-01T08:35:15.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:52.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 11442 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080, 11130 kb/s, 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 24k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-01T08:35:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2017-04-01T08:35:15.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
[Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 00000000010ab340] Cannot find a valid font for the family Sans
[AVFilterGraph @ 00000000052c9280] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args 'fontfile=E\:\\ffmpegTool\\bin\\arialbd.ttf:fontsize=30: fontcolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text=%{expr\\:n+1}: box=1'
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: No such file or directory
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4):

2019 Windows builds seem to have changed syntax or something again; here's what works for me today:

```
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=C\\:/Windows/fonts/consola.ttf:fontsize=72:fontcolor='white':timecode='00\:00\:00\:00':rate=25:text='TCR\:':boxcolor=0x000000AA:box=1:x=860-text_w/2:y=960"
```

In my case, I'm running FFmpeg from PWD, not `C:`, so I have to specify font path `C:\` with escaped colon and forward-slash for folder/file path.

Answer (score 3):

Omit double quotes (`"`) around the whole filter, use them only for the path to font file and omit spaces after `:`:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf drawtext=fontfile="E\:\\ffmpegTool\\bin\\arialbd.ttf":fontsize=30:fontcolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text=%{expr\\\\\:n+1}:box=1 -y out.mp4
```

Also, your path to the font file is suspicious - try using the default Windows font path

`c:\Windows\Fonts\`,

so your command will be

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf drawtext=fontfile="c\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\arialbd.ttf":fontsize=30:fontcolor=black:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text=%{expr\\\\\:n+1}:box=1 -y out.mp4
```

Comment: It didn't work :( maybe it's the `Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file`?

Comment: No, default config file is *nix specific - it is the file `fonts.conf` (in the default directory `/etc/fonts/`). You are using Windows - probably you wrote incorrect path. I edited my answer, see it.

Comment: Apparently it's the `fontcolor` that keeps making the error. I omitted one by one and this is the working code `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf drawtext=fontsize=40:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\Arial.ttf':text=%{n}:box=1 -y out.mp4`
(`"`) didn't work. but (`'`) did. 
How very strange it's the `fontcolor`...

Comment: It seems as something impossible (in spite of that `black` is the default `fontcolor`). Did you try some other colors or the notation `fontcolor=0x000000` ?

Comment: Yes you're right. It seems it's the part `text=%{expr\\\\\:n+1}` that caused something wrong. I forgot I also omitted that part at the same time. `fontcolor` works as expected. Thanks!

Comment: It'd be great to know why `text=%{expr\\\\\:n+1}` Do you have an idea?

Comment: You have odd number of backslashes. Try adding or removing one of them (or removing more of them). Other problem is that Windows command line itself interprets `%`, so you have to use it in a pair: `%%{expr ....`

Comment: Yes. It seems to be the backslashes. I think `%` is fine though. It's part of ffmpeg filter [syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Text-expansion)

Answer (score 1):

Windows UNC path can avoid colon using, change

```
fontfile='E\:\\ffmpegTool\\bin\\arialbd.ttf'
```

into

```
fontfile=//localhost/e$/ffmpegTool/bin/arialbd.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @MarianD and @Omensan.

I have been frustrated with this issues for a few days. Have found comments regarding libraries that may be missing in ffmpeg. Have since been researching the difference between --enable-fontconfig and --enable-libfontconfig, but got nowhere. Today Google gave me this topic on StackExchange.

Your answer to escape the colon, and forward slashes finally made it work fo me correctly in VS2012, VB.net, on Windows 10.

```
-i "X:\path\input.jpg" -vf  "drawtext=text='Caption Text':fontfile=X\\\\:/path/arialbd.ttf:fontcolor=red:fontsize=96:x=100:y=100" "X:\path\output.jpg"
```

Please note where, in the example above, the quotes go, single or double. For clarity a string parameter can be enclosed with single quoutes, like

```
:fontcolor='green'
```

I noticed that for the input and output paths there was no need to escape the colon, and forward or backward slashes work fine, but the full string needed to be enclosed in double quotes. Maybe that was just for (my) paths with space characters.

@MarianD and @Omensan, if we ever meet, I have hugs for you ^_^. (pun intended)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).